# service bus 1.0 not showing up in web platform installer 4.6 for Window7

Tags: windows, servicebus

I am trying to install Service Bus 1.0 on a machine(VM). When i am searching for "Service Bus 1.0" in the web platform installer 4.6, it is not able to find it.

I downloaded .exe file manually from http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35374. When the setup runs, it redirects me to Web Platform Installer and there again i am not able to find service bus 1.0.

My operating system is windows 7 Professional Edition, 64 bit OS. V2012 installed. I also have SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

However with the same configuration(Window 7, 64 bit) my colleague is able to install the service bus 1.0 successfully through the web platform installer.

Any idea what is causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

search for "Windows Azure Pack: Service Bus 1.1" on the web platform installer

Comment: tried searching for that ,did not get any thing in result. Got "Your query returned zero result"

Comment: strange.  that finds it for me.  but just doing a "service bus 1.0" search doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue today. Make sure you have run windows updates and have Windows 7 Service Pack 1 installed. Check out [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/034ea6c0-a974-44e3-9d82-31237b6dc251/microsoft-web-platform-installer-couldnt-find-the-service-bus-10?forum=servbus) on the Azure forums. As soon as I updated to the service pack, Service Bus 1.0 started showing up. It would be nice if the Web Platform Installer would show all options and disable options that your OS is not compatible with...